# Debug React Native cli Android app on emulator with WebStorm [error]

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build, android-emulator

I want to debug a React Native cli app in WebStorm using an Android emulator. I already created a new emulator in Android Studio and created a referance in WebStorm for it as an external tool. If I start it I get:

```
C:\Users\aerith\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -avd Pixel4TestDevice
INFO    | Android emulator version 31.3.10.0 (build_id 8807927) (CL:N/A)
emulator: INFO: Found systemPath C:\Users\aerith\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-33\google_apis\x86_64\
INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
INFO    | IPv4 server found: 172.17.0.11
INFO    | added library vulkan-1.dll
INFO    | configAndStartRenderer: setting vsync to 60 hz
INFO    | Sending adb public key 
INFO    | injectedQemuChannel!
INFO    | Informing listeners of injection.
INFO    | Rootcanal has  been activated.
WHPX on Windows 10.0.19044 detected.
Windows Hypervisor Platform accelerator is operational
INFO    | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local, auth: none
INFO    | Advertising in: C:\Users\aerith\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\pid_13836.ini
WARNING | *** No gRPC protection active, consider launching with the -grpc-use-jwt flag.***
INFO    | setDisplayConfigs w 1080 h 2400 dpiX 420 dpiY 420
```

I also created a new run configuration for React Native in WebStorm and executed it. If i then run `react-native run-android` in the project terminal i get this error and it wont start the app on the emulator:

```
info JS server already running.
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: Emulator exited before boot..
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...
> Task :app:installDebug FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
38 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 36 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
                                        
* What went wrong:                      
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

    at makeError (/home/aerith/dev/MatterAppPrototype/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /home/aerith/dev/MatterAppPrototype/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/home/aerith/dev/MatterAppPrototype/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)       
    at async Command.handleAction (/home/aerith/dev/MatterAppPrototype/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:142:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Could anyone help me how to debug my React Native project? I currently need to build and apk and install it every time i want to test it.

Alternative: Is there a way to debug on WebStorm with a real device and if yes how (current Android version is 6)?